# Check if multisession is running in future R

Tags: r, r-future

Is there a quick way to check if multiple processes were generated by `future` package on the current R?

In other words, to check whether `plan(multisession)` or similar was run in R?

Comment: Doesn't `plan()` return the current plan? I'd guess you can check that return.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if it sounds foolish but is there a way to return `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on that?

Comment: `is(future::plan() ,"multisession")`

Comment: Which OS is used? On Linux, one can use `ps` or `htop` from a bash shell, on Window, use the task manager.

Comment: @RicVillalba Please post the answer and I will accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is said in the comments, you can check (in the main process) the class of the object (a function) returned by `plan()` with no arguments.

```
library(future)

is(plan(), "multisession")   # TRUE if plan(multisession) is set FALSE otherwise
is(plan(), "sequential")     # ...
...
```